# Connect Fona3G SIM5320 to cloud over MQTT protocol using GPRS/TCP with stm32

Tags: stm32, gsm, tcp-ip, gprs, mqtt

I am seeking assistance in connecting the FONA 3G SIM5320 module to the cloud via TCP connect to establish an MQTT connection. I have successfully connected the module using GPRS connectivity by executing the following AT commands: AT+CGATT=1, AT+CGSOCKCONT="IP', APN, and AT+NETOPEN="tcp",1883.

However, I am facing difficulties when attempting to establish a TCP connection using the command: AT+TCPCONNECT="test.mosquitto.org",1883. Unfortunately, my attempts have been unsuccessful thus far.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or support you can offer in resolving this issue. If you have experience or expertise in working with the SIM5320 module and MQTT connectivity, your insights would be invaluable.